# Azure Resources not display

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

In my Azure account, I have bought the All the stuff.

My developer was working with it but due to some issue, I have changed the password.

Again I have reset the password and when I logged and in the resources nothing display. Why?

My Website is working fine but In resource, nothing shows me.

Comment: Have you checked if any filtering is applied? Maybe it's just a viewing issue.

Comment: @adp no filtration applied I don't why this thing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you are in the right directory or subscription. It happens when you have several people working with same user and switching between subscriptions, directories...
[image]

Try checking your All resources blade filters:
[image]